# Why is facebook javascript login code causing endless loop?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I run this code the login pop up and my console logs start to run in an endless loop. I'm not sure if I'm using the FB.login() method right. On the condition that the user arrives at my app connected, I want to prompt for permissions, if they are granted, won't that return a 'connected' status that I should be checking for and handling if it is declined?

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

//if connected open permissions dialog

       FB.login(function(response) {
//if user grants permissions, make ajax call to pass signed request to php page

       if(response.status === 'connected'){


               $.ajax({
        url : "http://xxxxxxio/bn/s_Request.php",
        type : 'POST',
        data: {signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest},
        success : function (result) {

           console.log(result);
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error parsing signed request");
        }
      });//closes ajax 

            }else{
                //if authorization cancelled, redirect to home page

                     window.location = "http://spilot.kd.io/bn/index.php";

                }//closes else

 }, {scope: 'user_location,user_likes'});

      testAPI();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app

     FB.login(function(response) {
             // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_location,user_likes'});

    } else {
      //  the person is not logged into Facebook, call the login() 

      FB.login(function(response) {
             // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_location,user_likes'});

    }//closes else

  });//closes event subscribe

var testAPI = function() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  };
```

Comment: No, FB.login does not return a "connected". Please log it’s return value to your browser’s console, so you’ll see what you actually get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user arrives to your app "connected" then he/she has already passed through your app authorization and supplied the necessary permissions. See this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

> FB.getLoginStatus allows you to determine if a user is logged in to
>   Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible
>   states for a user:
>
> - the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application (**connected**)
> - the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application (**not_authorized**)
> - the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (**unknown**)

CBroe is right, you want to monitor the response you get from each call, `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange'` is returning a different response from  `FB.login`

*If you want to supply "more" permissions*, you can issue them later on in your application.

To decrease redundancy we can pull out this function

```
FB.login(function(response) {
             // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_location,user_likes'});
```

and place into something like

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
                 // handle the response
     }, {scope: 'user_location,user_likes'});
}
```

So then you can have the last two parts of the conditional such as

```
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // not_authorized
    login();
} else {
  // not_logged_in
    login();
}
```

**I took a quick browse through your previous questions, and it seems you are getting the hang of it but it's a really rocky roundabout hacky way of getting there. So to avoid this altogether so you get the big picture, I suggest taking a step back looking at your app overall and return to the main goal of what you are trying to do**.

It sounds like you are sending signed_request via AJAX to PHP SDK (?) when the PHP SDK should already have a library of functions to take care of this. So yeah, take a step back and come back with a condensed form of the problem.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for the thorough answer and the tips. I'm still learning a lot so this was helpful.